# How to track user activity in node js application without a login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies

I have a node js application which displays graphs based on the selected parameters, these parameters can vary based on a users interest. I would like to collect information about a users activity , so that the next time the same user uses the application, it should display relevant feeds based on the graphs visualised before.

Can I do this without having to register a user in the db? How will the application remember every unique user? Can we do this via cookies?

Comment: you can store user information in localStorage in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to store user information server side, you could try cookies or browser storages like [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) and then requests that attached with parameters can be recognized what the user's preferences are.